# Vertices not perfectly aligned in tikz-feynamn

Tags: tikz-feynman

When trying to create a simple Feyman diagram (with the `tikz-feynman` package) using this code and compiling with LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{feynman}
      \vertex (a) {$\gamma$};
      \vertex [below=2cm of a] (b) {$e^-$};
      \vertex [above right=1cm and 1.5cm of b] (c);
      \vertex [right=2cm of c] (d);
      \vertex [above right=1cm and 1.5cm of d] (e) {$\gamma$};
      \vertex [below right=1cm and 1.5cm of d] (f) {$e^-$};
    
      \diagram* {
        (a) -- [photon] (c) -- [fermion, edge label=$e^-$] (d) -- [photon] (e),
        (b) -- [fermion] (c),
        (d) -- [fermion] (f)};
    \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I end up with this result:

[image]

And as you can see, for some reason, the (e) and (f) vertices are not aligned horizontally with the (a) and (b) vertices and we can also see that the vertical spacing between (e) and (f) is not the same as for (a) and (b), even though, in my code, the spacing should be correct. But now, if I add `{}` at the line where I define vertex (d), then here is what I get:

[image]

The horizontal and vertical spacing is good but there is a hole.

How can I get the same vertical and horizontal spacing as in the second picture but without the hole ?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: If I recall correctly, you need to compile with LuaLatex. Please check the manual, just to be sure.

Comment: @MS-SPO I'm already compiling with LuaLaTeX :(

Comment: Ok. Suggestion: Add this remark to your question, so it's easier to find today and the years after. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have redefine your code thus:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b] {
  c [particle=\(e^{-}\)] -- [fermion] a -- [photon] d [particle=\(\gamma\)],
  a -- [fermion, edge label=\(e^-\)] b,
  e [particle=\(\gamma\)] -- [photon] b -- [fermion] f [particle=\(e^{-}\)],
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]